# How to set cookie in the response using Axios in a Express/MongoDB project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I'm creating a CTF where the vulnerability is CSRF. In the CTF the user makes a request to the backend by specifying a URL and the backend will make a request to that URL. I want the request to the user specified URL to contain session cookie of the backend "support" user. Here is the code. I removed some irrelevant parts:

```js
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoDBSession = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session)
const axios = require('axios')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()

const CreateDefaultUsers = () => {
    try {
        User.create({
            username: "guest",
            password: "guest"
        })
        User.create({
            username: "support",
            password: "639Mydd&ou6Y"
        })
        console.log("User Created...")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating users")
    }
}


const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.log(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'), CreateDefaultUsers())

const store = new MongoDBSession({
    uri: mongoURI,
    collection: 'csrf-sessions'
})

app.use(session({
    name: "SESS_COOKIE",
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, secure: false, httpOnly: false, sameSite: false
    }
}))


app.post('/api/login-support', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    const user = await User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })
    if (user) {
        req.session.userId = user._id.toString();
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        res.send(req.session)
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({ status: "Invalid Login" });
    }
})


app.post('/api/support', async (req, res) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/login-support', { username: "support", password: "639Mydd&ou6Y" }, { withCredentials: true })
        .then((data) => axios.get(req.body.url, { headers: { Cookie: data } }, { withCredentials: true })
            .then((data) => console.log(data)))
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The `CreateDefaultUsers()` function will execute when the server is started. This will create 2 users (guest and support). When the user makes a request to `/api/support`, I'm having axios make a request to `http://localhost:5000/api/login-support` to get a session cookie for the support user. When that function returns I'm making a request to `req.body.url`, this is the user supplied URL that will contain a CSRF payload. The issue is that the `req.body.url` request does not contain the cookie.

If there is a better way to do this please let me know. I have tried with Zombie.js, but it didn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a combination of axios and zombie.js. I made a request using axios and got the cookie from the header:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/login-support', { username: "support", password: "639Mydd&ou6Y" }, { withCredentials: true })
  .then((data) => {
    const cookie = data.headers['set-cookie'][0].split(";")[0].split("SESS_COOKIE=")[1]
    console.log(cookie)
    reset(cookie)
  })
})
```

I then used zombie.js to execute the CSRF PoC:

```
const reset = async (cookie) => {
  const browser = new Browser();
  browser.setCookie({ name: 'SESS_COOKIE', value: cookie });
  browser.visit(req.body.url, () => {
    console.log('Browser is visiting URL')
  });
}
```